# WSO2 Identity Server nodes do not join cluster using ELB

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

currently I'm working in a project and I have an issue implementing ELB as a load balancer and Identity Server as an Identity and PDP provider in a cluster.

I would appreciate so much any help you can give me with the following implementation:

**The scenario**

- Two ELB in fail-over mode with a virtual IP virtual and KeepAlive, each node in separated machines
- One ESB cluster ESB with one manager node and two workers nodes; these nodes are in other  machines separated from the ELB nodes.
- One IS cluster with two nodes; these ones are in different machines separated from ELB and ESB machines.
- I have Open LDAP as User Store
- SVN as an artifact repository for syncing using Hazelcast
- All the nodes have a shared UM DB and a shared registry
- I have applied all the patches available for kernel 4.2.0 to the nodes of ELB, IS and ESB (patch 0010 inclusive)

The ELB nodes start correctly, the same for the ESB nodes which join the cluster without any problems; I can verify this in the ELB and ESB wso2carbon.log; also I validated the load balancing when I send requests to the ESB worker nodes from the ELB.

But, when I start the first IS node I get the following messages in  wso2carbon.log of IS

TID: [0] [IS] [2015-05-18 20:09:30,178]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent} -  Cluster domain: example.wso2is.domain {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent}

TID: [0] [IS] [2015-05-18 20:09:30,179]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent} -  Using wka based membership management scheme {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent}

TID: [0] [IS] [2015-05-18 20:09:30,180]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.util.MemberUtils} -  Added member: Host:IP_Virtual_ELB, Remote Host:null, Port: 4050, HTTP:-1, HTTPS:-1, Domain: null, Sub-domain:null, Active:true {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.util.MemberUtils}

TID: [0] [IS] [2015-05-18 20:09:35,468]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent} -  Hazelcast initialized in 5286ms {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent}

TID: [0] [IS] [2015-05-18 20:09:35,546]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent} -  Local member: [4c91357f-b563-49a2-b71b-887b3109642a] - Host:IP_Nodo1_Identity, Remote Host:null, Port: 4301, HTTP:9763, HTTPS:9443, Domain: example.wso2is.domain, Sub-domain:mgt, Active:true {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent}

TID: [0] [IS] [2015-05-18 20:09:35,558]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.util.MemberUtils} -  Added member: Host:IP_Nodo1_Identity, Remote Host:null, Port: 4301, HTTP:9763, HTTPS:9443, Domain: interacciones.wso2is.domain, Sub-domain:mgt, Active:true {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.util.MemberUtils}

TID: [0] [IS] [2015-05-18 20:09:35,650]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent} -  Cluster initialization completed {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent}

TID: [0] [IS] [2015-05-18 20:09:35,652]  INFO {org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool} -  may 18, 2015 8:09:35 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMACIÓN: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
 {org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool}

TID: [0] [IS] [2015-05-18 20:09:35,653]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent} -  Elected this member [4c91357f-b563-49a2-b71b-887b3109642a] as the Coordinator for the cluster [example.wso2is.domain] {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent}

And the  wso2carbon.log of ELB does not have any messages referring to this IS node that is just starting.

The services defined in loadbalancer.conf of ELB are as follows:

```
esb {     
     domains {    
               example.wso2esb.domain { 
               tenant_range *; 
               group_mgt_port 4000; 
            worker { 
                    hosts wso2esb.example.com; 
            } 
         } 
       } 
    } 

identity {
    domains { 
         example.wso2is.domain { 
            tenant_range *; 
            group_mgt_port 4050; 
            mgt{ 
                hosts wso2is.example.com; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

If I try to access from a client PC the IS console using the cirtual IP of the ELB, I get the following message in the ELB log:

TID: [0] [ELB] [2015-05-19 13:13:31,705] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.lb.endpoint.endpoint.TenantAwareLoadBalanceEndpoint} -  No application members available {org.wso2.carbon.lb.endpoint.endpoint.TenantAwareLoadBalanceEndpoint}

the content of /etc/hosts is:

***Client:***

ELB_Virtual_IP wso2is.example.com

ELB_Virtual_IP wso2esb.example.com

ESB_Manager_IP mgt.wso2esb.example.com

***ELB nodes:***

ELB_Virtual_IP wso2is.example.com

ELB_Virtual_IP wso2esb.example.com

ESB_Manager_IP mgt.wso2esb.example.com

***IS Node:***

ELB_Virtual_IP wso2is.example.com

***ESB nodes:***

ELB_Virtual_IP wso2is.example.com

ELB_Virtual_IP wso2esb.example.com

ESB_Manager_IP mgt.wso2esb.example.com

axis2.xml of IS node (clustering section)

```
    <parameter name="AvoidInitiation">true</parameter>

    <parameter name="membershipScheme">wka</parameter>
    <parameter name="domain">example.wso2is.domain</parameter>

    <parameter name="mcastPort">45564</parameter>

    <parameter name="mcastTTL">100</parameter>

    <parameter name="mcastTimeout">60</parameter>

    <parameter name="localMemberHost">IS_NODE_IP</parameter>
    <parameter name="localMemberPort">4301</parameter>
   <parameter name="properties">
        <property name="backendServerURL" value="https://${hostName}:${httpsPort}/services/"/>
        <property name="mgtConsoleURL" value="https://${hostName}:${httpsPort}/"/>
        <property name="subDomain" value="mgt"/>
    </parameter>

    <members>
        <member>
            <hostName>ELB_Virtual_IP</hostName>
            <port>4050</port>
        </member>
    </members>

    <groupManagement enable="false">
        <applicationDomain name="interacciones.wso2is.domain"
                           description="IS group"
                           agent="org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastGroupManagementAgent"
                           subDomain="mgt"
                           port="4301"/>
    </groupManagement>
</clustering>
```

carbon.xml of IS Node

```
<HostName>wso2is.example.com</HostName>

<MgtHostName>wso2is.example.com</MgtHostName>
```

Comment: Recently I have discovered that  ELB recognizes the IS nodes if it is patched just until patch00009 but does not recognizes the ESB nodes.  Also if the ELB is patched until patch0010 then it recognizes the ESB nodes but does not recognizes the IS nodes. It seems to me there is an inconsistency when applying the carbon kernel patches with the implementation of the Hazelcast library which deals with all the stuff related to nodes sync.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is Hazelcast issue after applying the kernel patch to the ELB. No configuration issue can see in the given configs.Please check any Hazelcast related fix for this issue with the Wso2 meanwhile you can check removing kernel patch0009 and patch0010.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I have tested the ELB without any patches, I mean out of the box testing and does not work neither with ESB nor with IS.  I have the ESB patched until patch0010 and also the IS along with security patches suggested in the wso2 site.  The reason of the security patches and all of these stuff is this deployment eventually comes to production.